# How do you set the Content-Type header for an HttpClient request with MultipartFormDataContent?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I looked at the MS Source code according to their interpretation the HttpClient itself does not have "Content-Type" only the content should have content-type. Seems logical except when you're dealing with MultipartFormDataContent.
MultipartFormDataContent completely ignores the following code:

```
string boundary = "--" + GenerateRandomString();
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue($"multipart/form-data");
    content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("boundry", boundary));
    ...
}
```

No "Content-Type" is present in the request.
And also ignores:

```
string boundary = "--" + GenerateRandomString();
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
{
    content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    ...
}
```

Attemting to set it at on the HttpClient

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
```

throws the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'`

I can find plenty of examples of how to do this using StringContent but none with MultipartFormDataContent. MultipartFormDataContent allows setting the Content-Type and Content-Disposition with each field, I need this more at the client level. I need a header that looks something like this:

```
accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Authorization: Basic ZXlKbGRDSTZJakUxTWpZNU9UTXpOTnpkMjl5WkNJNklqa3haRGxtWkdKa1lUazRaVEJqWmpsalpUaGxNV1V3TXpOalxuWmpCbE1tVXhJaXdpZFhObGNpSTZJbUZrYldsdUluMD1cbjo=
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Many non-Microsoft APIs require the "boundary" tag so it can distinguish the individual fields of data being sent. The validation here on the request seems a little over the top. Even TryAddWithoutValidation doesn't work (maybe a bug?). I realize that it may be possible to interpret RFC7578 in a way that says it shouldn't be required but flat out not allowing it doesn't seem right to me either. Anyone else ever run into this issue and solve it.

Comment: But `MultipartFormDataContent` already sets Content-Type header correctly by itself (with boundary), so seems no additional efforts required? I just tested with `HttpClient` in .NET 4.6 and it sends Content-Type just fine

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't do that for me. I am using latest .Net Standard, so maybe it actually is a bug? I thought that it should do it automatically and I was surprised not to see it in the request header. I recorded the request with Fiddler and also used HttpLoggingHandler to dump the request out to file.

Comment: @user2033791 what runtime did you target? .NET Standard isnt' a runtime. HttpClient itself is available through the [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http) package. Which version did you use?

Comment: I can't reproduce any issue using `MultipartFormDataContent` even when the call to `HttpClient.PostAsync` is in a .NET Standard 2.0 library. The boundary is there and so is the content type. No header manipulations were needed

Comment: How do you know there is a problem? Did you inspect the HTTP request with a proxy like Fiddler ir did you get a server error and assumed it's the boundary?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought this was an HttpClient bug. I added logging to capture the request and the response. That logging was missing headers which lead me to believe that the missing "multi-part/form-data" content header was the issue and the reason the API I'm using kept telling me it couldn't find a required field. It turns out to be an issue with how the API handles the data it's sent when it's multi-part/form-data. After comparing both my HttpWebRequest and the HttpClient request in fiddler I discovered the following difference in the data being sent:

**HttpWebRequest**

```
----vekhftkcthxr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name";

d30-20180524
```

**HttpClient**

```
----bcgifxyjkmkw
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=name

d30-20180524
```

I build the HttpWebRequest manually so I included the quotes and ending semi-colons. The HttpClient request is built for me and does not include the extra quotes and semi-colon. So the API I am using does not play well with request being generated by the HttpClient even though the request is technically correct.

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos for showing me my error.

Comment: Confirmed *how*? .NET Standard isn't a *target runtime*. You can't create a .NET Standard executable. Which runtime and *version* did you target? Even if you put the code in a .NET Standard library which version did you target?

Comment: No repro in .NET Core 2.0. Using MultipartFormDataContent by itself sends the boundary

Comment: No repro either when the code is in a .NET Standard library, called by a console application. In both cases the content type and the boundary are there. You can't expect a fix from Microsoft when the issue can't be reproduced

Comment: It works in a .Net 4.5 project in Visual Studio. It does not work if you create a .Net standard library with a .Net Core 2.0 project.

Comment: No repro in that scenario either. Did you try to post *without* trying to modify the headers? What code did you use to test the problem, which package versions did you use? What is the package version of your NETStandard.Library package? In a new class library project it's 2.0.3

Comment: Yes my first attempt was without trying to modify the headers. When all of the calls failed I started logging the request (headers and body) and the response. The response I was seeing from the API I was posting to was "Required Field XXXX was missing". Seemed like a weird error because I saw the filed and data present in the body. Then I noticed that the header was missing and it made sense, it couldn't parse the data without the field boundary.  Test Project was .Net Core 2.0 using Xunit. The Client was .Net Standard 2.0.0

Comment: And I repeat, no repro. Try again with *Fiddler* instead of logging and check the actual content of the request. Create a simple .NET Core 2.0 console application and a simple .NET Standard 2.0 library

Comment: You are correct. The header does show up in fiddler, but it's not in present in my HttpRequestMessage logging. I will investigate further and modify my answer.